# Call another phone by it's IMEI?

Tags: java-me

I want to make an application by j2me that call  another  phone by it's IMEI

can this possible?

if possible I want some guidelines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt that this is possible, on a J2ME phone, or any other mobile platform.

The IMEI number is a unique *serial* number for a handset.  The mobile carrier knows which IMEI numbers go with which phone numbers (although this mapping can change, for example by swapping SIM cards).  However, they won't (at least in the US, where I live) give out a mapping between IMEI and phone numbers.  That would be a breach of privacy.

So, you can't lookup the phone number, and thus, can't make the call.

[See here for some more discussion of this topic](http://community.flexispy.com/index.php?/topic/486-can-i-find-a-mobile-number-by-searching-the-imei/)

[... and here, too](http://www.cnet.com/8301-17918_1-20020198-85.html)

I'm also assuming that you're not building an app in conjunction with the police, and the mobile carriers, in a country without significant privacy rights.  If you are, then maybe this is possible.  Everywhere else ... no.